# Find values in as sheet from a list in another sheet and color the whole row

Tags: vba, excel

I have values in sheet 1 in column I, which number can vary.

I want to find these values in Sheet 2 and to color the entire rows, where these values are in Sheet 2.

```
 Dim FindString As Range
 Dim Rng As Range

        FindString = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I2" &  _
        .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value

        If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
            With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:AZ500")
                Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                    'Application.Goto Rng, True
                Else

                End If
            End With
        End If

        With Rng.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .Color = 255
        End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindString` was in fact an array, so I changed its declaration.

But you'll need to loop on that array to search for all values :
 `For i = LBound(FindString, 1) To UBound(FindString, 1)`

And as you may not have this value only one time in the 2nd sheet, you'll need to use `FindNext`

```
Dim FindString() As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim LastRow As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If LastRow > 2 Then
        FindString = .Range("J2:J" & LastRow).Value
    Else
        ReDim FindString(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        FindString(1,1) = .Range("J2").Value
    End If
End With 'Sheets("Sheet1")

For i = LBound(FindString, 1) To UBound(FindString, 1)
    If Trim(FindString(i, 1)) <> vbNullString Then
        With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:AZ500")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString(i, 1), _
                            After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)


            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                With Rng
                    FirstAddress = .Address
                    Do
                        With .EntireRow.Interior
                            .Pattern = xlSolid
                            .Color = 255
                        End With
                        Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                    'Look until you find again the first result
                    Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
                End With 'Rng
            End If
        End With 'Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:AZ500")
    Else
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I receive an application defined or object defined error. The problem is by the defining of the FindString

Comment: @AntonPetrov : my bad, I forgot the `:I` that was necessary! Give it another try! ;)

Comment: Yes it works now. Thank you very much. I have just one more question. How can I make it that it colors the whole row in  Sheet 2 and not just the cell with the value?

Comment: @AntonPetrov : Try the edit! ;) I added `.EntireRow` which should do the trick!

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you

Comment: to color only cells in A:AZ columns use `With Intersect(.EntireRow,Range("A:AZ")).Interior`

Comment: @R3uK I tried to chnage the colum to `FindString = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:J" & _
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & _
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value` but it gives me type dismatch

Comment: @AntonPetrov : Do you have more than one cell? ie is J3 filled?

Comment: @R3uK J3 is empty in this case

Comment: @AntonPetrov : That's why you have an error! Fill it and it'll work! You can't load a single cell like this in an array!

Comment: @R3uK the problem is that the content of this column changes. It can be only one cell or 10

Comment: @AntonPetrov : I'm such in a good mood that I did edit my answer, so please upvote it too! ;)

Answer (score 1):

edited to add solution

you're dimming `FindString As Range`, but then using it as an array (`FindString = someRange.Value`)

you'd better off using `AutoFilter()`

I'm not sure if you are searching for FindString values among column A or among columns A:AZ of Sheet2 , so I post the code for both options

---

**searching for FindString values among column A of Sheet2**

```
Sub main2()
    Dim FindString As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        FindString = Application.Transpose(.Range("I2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1)).Value)
    End With
    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:AZ500")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FindString, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .Color = 255
            End With
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**searching for FindString values among columns A:AZ of Sheet2**

```
Option Explicit

Sub main2()
    Dim FindString As Variant
    Dim col As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        FindString = Application.Transpose(.Range("I2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1)).Value)
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:AZ500")
        For Each col In .Columns
            .AutoFilter Field:=col.Column, Criteria1:=FindString, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, col.Cells) > 1 Then
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .Color = 255
                End With
            End If
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: it does not color the rows

Comment: are `FindString` values to be searched among column A of `Sheet2`, or are they to to be searched among columns A:AZ of `Sheet2`?